# Advice needed : database update to rest of team

Tags: database, version-control, updates, auto-update

Wanted to get your opinions.

When working in a team and using a version control system, at some point one developer will commit code that depends on new modifications that he made to his local database.

Well, once the other team members update the code, their local db is not ready for it.

Is there a nice way to handle this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's your development platform?

Some web frameworks have 'database migration' features for this purpose, e.g:

1. [Rails migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)
2. [CodeIgniter migration class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html)
3. [FuelPHP migrations](http://docs.fuelphp.com/general/migrations.html)
4. [Yii Framework database migration](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration)

Comment: Not something I've used. But what about [flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/)?

Comment: Nice, it looks like what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.
Are there other approaches besides looking for a language specific database migration tool ? Excluding emailing the team :)

Comment: Great. If this was what you were looking for you should accept my answer - people can still reply with other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) is good and The Right Thing (tm) for managing database evolution during development